# Checking if the number of a String is even with regex Java

Tags: java, eclipse

i want to check if the number of a `String` is even with regex.

```
public static boolean check5(String s){
    Pattern p5 = Pattern.compile("(..)*");
    Matcher m5 = p5.matcher(s);
    if (m5.find()){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is he returns always true and i don't know why?

Comment: what do you expect `(..)*` to do?

Comment: With wich `String` do you expect to get `false`and which other `String, `true`

Comment: I expect that if he checks two arbitrary characters its always straight because everything multiplied with 2 is even.

Comment: Are you trying to know if the number **of characters** in a string is even? How about `string.length() % 2 == 0`?

Comment: are you wanting to check the length of string as even?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args){
 int a = 15, b = 30;
 char[] i = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
 int n = 10

Comment: string.length is not a regex

Comment: for (String s : woerter){
     System.out.println(s + ": " + check5(s));
 }

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a regular expression for this; they are not really designed for verifying numeric *values*.

Instead, parse the `String` into an integral type (`num`, say), reject if any exception is thrown, then use

`num % 2 == 0`

as your test for evenness. If, for some reason, you absolutely *must* use a regular expression, then use something on the lines of `[0-9]*[02468]`. It drops out surprisingly simply for a test of divisibility by 2, as would 5 and 10. But try working out a regular expression to test divisibility by 3, let alone 7.

Finally, if I have completely the wrong end of the stick here and all you want to do is check if the length of `s` is even then again, don't use a regular expression, but

`s.length() % 2 == 0`

as the check.

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex to below for checking if the string length is even.

```
Pattern p5 = Pattern.compile("^(..)*$");
```

It matches zero or more sets of two characters, all of which is anchored to the start and end of the string

Comment: Upvoted; this is quite elegant and, unlike me, you don't patronise the OP. Do accept this answer when you can.

Answer (score 0):

Matcher.find() will search an occurrence or regexp in the given String.
For (..)* will search any two characters zero or more times.
Therefore "ABC" will make find()=true as it can find "AB" or "BC".
So use Matcher.matches() instead